# How can I use "bigbluebutton" in my Web Application?

Tags: java, jsf

I would like to add a feature `Web Conference` in my application.

1. Can we combine `bigbluebutton` web conference system to my application?
2. Which API is used Web Conference for java web application?

Currently, my web application is used JSF 2.0

Comment: @Dominik, my question is "Is it ok or not?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CycDemo,

I'm one of the developers of BigBlueButton.  The way to "embed" BigBlueButton in your application is not to think in terms of embedding the server into your server; rather, think of running a second BigBlueButton server and using the BigBlueButton API to create rooms, launch users into rooms, and query the BigBlueButton server for recordings afterwards.

You can see how to do this in our [API documentation](http://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/wiki/API).

Also, check out the API examples (.jsp) for how to call the BigBlueButton API.  See [source for API demos](https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton/tree/master/bbb-api-demo/src/main/webapp).

### Regards,.. Fred

BigBlueButton Developer

Comment: thanks for your help, I will reference it.

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't know if it is ok or not, but you can use [BigBlueButton](http://www.bigbluebutton.org/) (LGPL) or [OpenMeetings](http://incubator.apache.org/openmeetings/) (ASL), both have APIs to connect with external apps.

Comment: thanks for your reference. OpenMeetings meeting will be useful for web conferencing in my application.